# How to apply a random lock screen image from a folder

Tags: windows, powershell, locking, screen, msi-patch

I need to be able to set the Lock Screen from a local folder

Set it so every time the device is locked it will randomly pick from this folder and make it so it doesn't pick the same image twice

This needs to be pushed out to all users. Either through InTune or GPO

Setting a task in task scheduler but each device has a separate local admin

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).